# How do I limit Google Maps API results to prevent returning estimate on addresses that do not exist

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I am creating a button on a web page to return the latitude and longitude of an address entered into a form using google maps. This works great when the address is valid but also returns results for invalid addresses. I have tried using the geometry.location_type to limit to rooftop location types but this is not good enough since google returns "rooftop" for such queries as "1 b fl" or "1 atlanta ga" - clearly invalid addresses. In the case of "1 atlanta ga" it returns a formatted_address of "401 Moreland Ave NE, Atlanta, GA 30307, USA". How do I make sure that it only returns accurate - or at least sort of accurate - results? I am not getting error messages to show up in these cases.

I tried using the location_type key but that seems to return "ROOFTOP" even in the above examples. I don't see any other keys that specify accuracy.

```
function geocodeAddress(address) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            var locationType = results[0].geometry.location_type;
            if (results.length > 1) {
                $('#errorMessage').text('Too many results')
            } else {
                if (locationType != "ROOFTOP") {
                    $('#errorMessage').text('May not be accurate')
                }
             $('#Location_Latitude').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
             $('#Location_Longitude').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Unable to get coordinates at this time: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

I would like to see the error message, "May not be accurate" show up any time a close to exact match cannot be found. I say close to exact because I don't want the results to throw an error if the user doesn't type it in exactly as it is in the database and because I am only asking for address, city, and state so the country and zip code could be null.

This is the result I get back using the Georgia example above:

```
0:
address_components: (9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
formatted_address: "401 Moreland Ave NE, Atlanta, GA 30307, USA"
geometry:
location: _.R {lat: ƒ, lng: ƒ}
location_type: "ROOFTOP"
viewport: _.Cd {na: Bd, ga: xd}
__proto__: Object
place_id: "ChIJJ72T1agG9YgR7f1FJRUZsEc"
plus_code: {compound_code: "QM82+3F Atlanta, Georgia, United States", global_code: "865QQM82+3F"}
types: (5) ["bar", "establishment", "food", "point_of_interest", "restaurant"]
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Yeah, I get `"3232 Peachtree Rd Unit A1, Atlanta, GA 30305, USA"` running the same query: `1 atlanta ga`. Would it be possible to have your user select the point on a map and then reverse geocode for more accuracy?

Comment: If that is not possible, then have a peek at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete - this should help sanitise your input and deliver clean addresses.

Comment: Geocoder is not an address validation service, it just try to resolve input string you provide to some coordinate. If a quality of string is bad, the result is also bad. Geocoder was never designed as address validation tool. Probably place autocomplete might be more suitable. You start typing and select an address from suggested list.

Comment: Unfortunately they are filling out a form with their address and GPS coordinates. There is no map on this page. Since people don't know their GPS coordinates this button would take the address they provide and get the GPS coordinates. Those coordinates are stored in a database for use later. @DavidP I'll check out the link you provided.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a combination of this and autocomplete. I had to use both because autocomplete wouldn't fill in the top result on blur and I didn't want the user to have to click on one. If you know of a better way, please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Check the "partial match" value in the response:

**https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#geocoding**

> - partial_match indicates that the geocoder did not return an exact match for the original request, though it was able to match part of the requested address. You may wish to examine the original request for misspellings and/or an incomplete address.
> - Partial matches most often occur for street addresses that do not exist within the locality you pass in the request. Partial matches may also be returned when a request matches two or more locations in the same locality. For example, "21 Henr St, Bristol, UK" will return a partial match for both Henry Street and Henrietta Street. Note that if a request includes a misspelled address component, the geocoding service may suggest an alternative address. Suggestions triggered in this way will also be marked as a partial match.

Comment: I tried that, however it does not return partial_match in these examples. I have seen that before, but in many cases it does not indicate a partial match. I edited my question above to show what I get returned.